# Eclipse can't connect to Internet

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt

I'm using Eclipse IDE for C/C++ Developers Version: Juno Service Release 1.

- I'm not using a proxy.
- I have disabled both antivirus and firewall.
- In "Network Connections", i put "Active Provider" in "Direct".

Still Eclipse fails to connect to internet.

I'm missing something ?

Thanks for your help.